# Resolved Frequencies of a Fourier Transform from a Time series

Tags: matlab, fft, tidalcycles

I have a time series of some tidal data which is given as the following:
[image: Original time series of Tidal Elevation Data]

If we take the FFT to determine the specific harmonics present in the data we see the the following: [image: FFT of Tidal Elevation data]

This FFT was computing using the matlab FFT function from the method presented here(https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/435508-how-can-i-get-proper-length-of-fft)

```
Fn = Fs/2;   % Nyquist Frequency
N = length(z); %Compute length of Elevation z
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(N); 
FTx = fft(z, NFFT) / N;
Fv = linspace(0, 1, fix(N/2)+1)*Fn*60*60*24;% Frequency Vector from seconds to days
Iv = 1:numel(Fv);    
figure(5)
semilogy(Fv, abs(FTx(Iv))*2)
grid on;
```

The issue is I know there are harmonics of the tide which occur on scales greater than 14 days however the basic FFT seems to choose the frequency limits it returns to 12 days despite my time series having many months of data, How can I force the FFT to incorporate those frequencies?

Comment: Your x-axis units in the code posted are cycles/day. So either you have extra steps you are not showing to do the conversion to days, or the x-axis label is wrong and the graph goes up to 12 cycles/day (and not 12 days), with long periods being displayed on the left side of the graph (e.g. a 12 day period would appear at x=1/12 cycles/day).

Comment: The output of the FFT is a frequency which means your x-axis labeling (and probably scaling) is incorrect.  It sounds like you want the output to be in period (1/frequency).  This would be a different scaling and labeling of the x-axis.